# How to measure Valgrind's memory usage?

Tags: valgrind, zmalloc

I have an application written in C which uses the `zmalloc` (borrowed from Redis) memory wrapper to keep track of the total dynamic allocated memory by my program. I am also using Valgrind on Linux to find memory leaks and invalid memory accesses.

The problem is that `zmalloc` and `top` show totally different memory usage reports when I am using Valgrind. This makes me think that Valgrind itself is consuming too much memory.

How do I measure Valgrind's memory usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valgrind tools such as memcheck or helgrind use a lot of memory for
tracking various aspects of your program.
So, it is normal that top shows a lot more memory than what your program
allocates itself.

If you want to have an idea about the memory used by valgrind, you can do:

```
valgrind --stats=yes ...
```

The lines following

------ Valgrind's internal memory use stats follow ------

will give some info about valgrind memory usage.

Use `valgrind --profile-heap=yes ...` to have detailed memory use.

Note that if you do not use the standard malloc library, you might need to use the option --soname-synonyms=...  to have tools such as memcheck or helgrind working properly.
to